# Merge arrays and toggle

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of ids:

```
let a = [1, 7, 8];
let b = [1, 7, 99];
```

I want to merge they and toggle off the common values. The result must be as follow:

```
let res = [8, 99];
```

Each array (`a` or `b`) can't have duplicates. So next is impossible

```
let a = [1, 1, 7, 8];
let b = [1, 7, 7, 99, 7];
```

How can I merge and toggle? I can merge this way without duplicates, but it is not I want.

```
[...new Set([...a, ...b])]; // [1, 7, 8, 99]
```

Comment: What means "toggle"? It seems that you want only the last item of each array in your new array.

Comment: By _toggling_, he means that if an ID is present in both arrays, they cancel each other and are not included in the resulting array.

Answer (score 5):

Using Array#filter on both with spread operator.

```js
let a = [1, 7, 8];
let b = [1, 7, 99];

const res = [...a.filter(item=>!b.includes(item)), ...b.filter(item=>!a.includes(item))];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

To avoid a *O(n²)* time complexity, make a set for one of both arrays

```js
const a = [1, 7, 8];
const b = [1, 7, 99];

const setA = new Set(a);
const res = [...b.filter(item => !setA.delete(item)), ...setA]; 

console.log(res);
```

Comment: More optimised than mine +1 should be the right answer.

Comment: I also liked this one! +1

Answer (score 3):

You could take a single set and reduce the second array.

```js
let a = [1, 7, 8],
    b = [1, 7, 99],
    result = [...b.reduce((s, v) => s.has(v) ? (s.delete(v), s) : s.add(v), new Set(a))];
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach by using a for-loop

```js
const a = [1, 7, 8];
const b = [1, 7, 99];
const arr = a.concat(b).sort((a, b) => a - b);
const result = [];
let currentId;

for (const id of arr) {
    if (currentId === id) {
        result.pop();
    } else {
        currentId = id;
        result.push(id);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

So, what you want is to calculate the `union` of the two arrays `minus` the `intersection` of they. Skipping the performance, I will do this step by step:

```js
let a = [1, 7, 8];
let b = [1, 7, 99];

// Calculate the union.
let union = new Set([...a, ...b]);

// Calculate the intersection.
let intersection = new Set(a.filter(x => b.includes(x)));

// Calculate union minus intersection.
let res = [...union].filter(x => !intersection.has(x));

console.log(res);
```

Or in a simplified way (not so readable like the previous one):

```js
let a = [1, 7, 8];
let b = [1, 7, 99];

// Calculate union minus intersection.
let res = [...a, ...b].filter(x => !(a.filter(y => b.includes(y))).includes(x));

console.log(res);
```

Even more simplified and readable would be one of the next options:

```js
let a = [1, 7, 8];
let b = [1, 7, 99];

// Calculate union minus intersection.
let res1 = [...a, ...b].filter(x => !(a.includes(x) && b.includes(x)));

console.log(res1);

// Or using Morgan’s Law:
let res2 = [...a, ...b].filter(x => !a.includes(x) || !b.includes(x));

console.log(res2);
```